# Error : can not read a block mapping entry; a multiline key may not be an implicit key at line 111, column 1: ^ Line : undefined undefined

Tags: sql, yaml, airflow

```
default_args:
  owner: x
  email: x@gmail.com
  retries: 3
  email_on_failure: True
  email_on_retry: False
  retry_delay: 5s
  start_date: 2020-10-18
dag:
  name: lms_statement
  schedule_interval: '@once'
tasks:
  create_table_task:
    action: create
    table: lms_statement_generation
    query: ' 
SELECT customer_id,stmt.id,CAST(from_iso8601_timestamp(opening_date) as timestamp) as opening_date,CAST(from_iso8601_timestamp(closing_date) as timestamp) as closing_date,stmt.credit_id,CAST(from_iso8601_timestamp(stmt.due_date) as timestamp) as due_date,opening_balance,closing_balance,closing_event_id,stmt.created_at,CAST(json_extract("full_statement",'$.summary.balance.purchase')AS decimal) as cycle_purchase_amount,CAST(json_extract("full_statement",'$.summary.balance.repayment')AS decimal) as cycle_repayment_amount,CAST(json_extract("full_statement",'$.summary.balance.penalty')AS decimal) as cycle_penalty_amount,CAST(json_extract("full_statement",'$.summary.balance.miscCredit')AS decimal) as cycle_misc_waiver_amount,bullet_risk_segment,bullet_affluence_segment,user_bullet_risk_score,user_bureau_score,bullet_limit,
credit_paid_till_bill_generation,penalty_paid_till_bill_generation,credit_paid_till_closing_date,penalty_paid_till_closing_date,
CAST(from_iso8601_timestamp(first_table.first_purchase_date) as timestamp) as first_purchase_date,CAST(from_iso8601_timestamp(first_table.first_repayment_date) as timestamp) as  first_repayment_date,
case
when cast(stmt.opening_balance as decimal)>0 and cast(json_extract("full_statement",'$.summary.balance.repayment') AS decimal)-opening_balance>=0 then 0.00
when cast(stmt.opening_balance as decimal)>0 and cast(json_extract("full_statement",'$.summary.balance.repayment') AS decimal)-opening_balance<0 then opening_balance-cast(json_extract("full_statement",'$.summary.balance.repayment') AS decimal)
when cast(stmt.opening_balance as decimal)<=0 then 0.00 end as carry_forward_due,
evt_settle.created_at as bill_generation_date,
appo.credit_outstanding AS credit_os_bill_generation,appo.penalty_outstanding AS penalty_os_bill_generation
FROM delta_lake_db.lms_public_event as evt_settle
LEFT JOIN delta_lake_db.lms_public_credit_statement AS stmt
ON stmt.closing_event_id = evt_settle.id
LEFT JOIN delta_lake_db.lms_public_credit_statement_apportionment as appo
ON evt_settle.id = appo.event_id
LEFT JOIN
(select credit_id, MIN(case when event_type = 11 then created_at end) AS first_purchase_date,
MIN(case when event_type = 6 then created_at end) AS first_repayment_date
FROM delta_lake_db.lms_public_event
GROUP BY credit_id) AS first_table
ON stmt.credit_id = first_table.credit_id
LEFT JOIN delta_lake_db.lms_public_credit AS credit
ON stmt.credit_id = credit.id
left join
(select (CASE
            WHEN credit_risk.customer_aff_A1 = 'true'
            THEN 'A1'
            WHEN credit_risk.customer_aff_A2 = 'true'
            THEN 'A2'
            WHEN credit_risk.customer_aff_A3 = 'true'
            THEN 'A3'
            ELSE 'Missing'
        END) AS bullet_affluence_segment,
(CASE
            WHEN credit_risk.customer_ris_R0 = '1'
            THEN 'R0'
            WHEN credit_risk.customer_ris_R1 = '1'
            THEN 'R1'
            WHEN credit_risk.customer_ris_R2 = '1'
            THEN 'R2'
            WHEN credit_risk.customer_ris_R3 = '1'
            THEN 'R3'
            ELSE 'Missing'
        END) AS bullet_risk_segment,
credit_risk.user_bullet_risk_score,
credit_risk.user_bureau_score,
credit_risk.bullet_limit,
customerId
FROM  (SELECT 
    responsetime,request,
    CAST(json_extract(request, "$.customerId") AS VARCHAR(100)) as customerId,
    CAST(json_extract(response, '$.riskResponse.limit')AS INTEGER) as bullet_limit,
    CAST(json_extract(response, '$.riskResponse.responseStatus') AS VARCHAR(100)) as bullet_decision,
    CAST(json_extract(response, '$.riskResponse.declineReasonCode') AS VARCHAR(100)) as decline_reason_code,
    CAST(json_extract(response, '$.riskResponse.riskDetails.results.isAffluenceA1')AS VARCHAR(100)) as customer_aff_A1,
    CAST(json_extract(response, '$.riskResponse.riskDetails.results.isAffluenceA2')AS VARCHAR(100)) as customer_aff_A2,
    CAST(json_extract(response, '$.riskResponse.riskDetails.results.isAffluenceA3')AS VARCHAR(100)) as customer_aff_A3,
    CAST(json_extract(response, '$.riskResponse.riskDetails.results.jupiterCreditScoreR0')AS VARCHAR(100)) as customer_ris_R0,
    CAST(json_extract(response, '$.riskResponse.riskDetails.results.jupiterCreditScoreR1')AS VARCHAR(100)) as customer_ris_R1,
    CAST(json_extract(response, '$.riskResponse.riskDetails.results.jupiterCreditScoreR2')AS VARCHAR(100)) as customer_ris_R2,
    CAST(json_extract(response, '$.riskResponse.riskDetails.results.jupiterCreditScoreR3')AS VARCHAR(100)) as customer_ris_R3,
    CAST(json_extract(response, '$.riskResponse.riskDetails.results.jupiterCreditScore')AS INTEGER) as user_bullet_risk_score,
    CAST(json_extract(response, '$.riskResponse.riskDetails.features.customerIdEQUIFAXbureauScore')AS INTEGER) as user_bureau_score
    FROM delta_lake_db.credit_risk_eligibility_events as t1a
    WHERE responsetime = (SELECT MAX(t2a.responsetime) 
    FROM delta_lake_db.credit_risk_eligibility_events as t2a
    WHERE CAST(json_extract(t1a.request, '$.customerId') AS VARCHAR(100)) = CAST(json_extract(t2a.request, '$.customerId') AS VARCHAR(100)) 
    AND CAST((CAST(from_iso8601_timestamp(t2a.responsetime) as timestamp) +interval '5' hour + interval '30' minute) as date) <= CAST((CAST(from_iso8601_timestamp('{{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')}}') as timestamp)+interval '5' hour + interval '30' minute) as Date)))as credit_risk) as risk_table

on risk_table.customerId=credit.customer_id
 left join 
 (select appo.statement_id,
sum(cast(appo.credit_change as decimal))*-1 as credit_paid_till_bill_generation,
sum(cast(appo.penalty_change as decimal))*-1 as penalty_paid_till_bill_generation,
sum(case when cast(from_iso8601_timestamp(appo.created_at) as timestamp)<=cast(concat(stmt.closing_date,' ','23:59:00') as timestamp)
then
cast(appo.credit_change as decimal) end)*-1
as credit_paid_till_closing_date,
sum(case when cast(from_iso8601_timestamp(appo.created_at) as timestamp)<=cast(concat(stmt.closing_date,' ','23:59:00') as timestamp)
then
cast(appo.penalty_change as decimal) end)*-1
as penalty_paid_till_closing_date
from
delta_lake_db.lms_public_credit_statement as stmt
inner join 
delta_lake_db.lms_public_event as evt_close
on stmt.closing_event_id = evt_close.id
inner join 
delta_lake_db.lms_public_credit_statement_apportionment as appo
on stmt.id = appo.statement_id and appo.created_at <= evt_close.created_at
inner join delta_lake_db.lms_public_event as evt
on appo.event_id = evt.id and evt.event_type in (6,7,9)
group by 1) as
 outstanding_table on outstanding_table.statement_id=stmt.id
WHERE evt_settle.event_type = 10 and CAST`enter code here`(from_iso8601_timestamp(evt_settle.created_at) as date) = CAST((CAST(from_iso8601_timestamp('{{execution_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')}}') as timestamp)+interval '5' hour + interval '30' minute) as Date)'
```

I am stuck on this problem for days now but different yaml formatter keep giving different errors now please help me in knowing where the problem lies. The YAML file shows error on line 14 column 5 stating

> did not find expected key while parsing a block in line 14 column 5

another parser says that

> Error : can not read a block mapping entry; a multiline key may not be an implicit key at line 111, column 1:
> ^
> Line : undefined  undefined

There is no definite answer I tried removing line to figure out where the problem is but found out that the problem was

Comment: I assume you are using https://pypi.org/project/dag-factory/ package?

Comment: yes i am using that to deploy it to airflow @Elad We had similart DAGs and there was no issue there. I ran the same query on jupyter and it had no issue whatsoever

Comment: I'm no expert on that package but where did you define which operator should run the SQL you mentioned? I would imagine that it supports reading query from file thus moving the SQL code outside of the YMAL file

Comment: Its like a pipeline. So there is this jobs.py file which will read the query file from this config and extract the query inside of it we had similar queries before bu there were no errors ther.

Comment: I believe this is a syntax error related to the single quote in your string. Try replacing `query: 'YOUR QUERY'` to: `query: """ YOUR QUERY """`

Comment: Thanks @Elad this has been sorted. I posted the answer for the same

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been sorted. When you write anything inside the "" in the query. You cannot use double quotes inside it. Here i had used json_extract("some_variable",'$.a.b')

this is not acceptable.

We can write either
json_extract('some_variable','$.a.b')
or
json_extract(some_variable,'$.a.b')